# how to stub URI(request.referrer).path to include 'cart'

Tags: rspec, http-referer

I'm writing an rspec test which fails at line

```
 if URI(request.referrer).path.include?('cart')
```

I want to be able to make the request.referrer include 'cart'

Please let me know if you have any approaches.

i tried the following and they didn't work:

```
@request.env['HTTP_REFERER']='http://localhost:port/account/cart/id'
post url, params
```

also tried:

```
post url, params, {"HTTP_REFERER" => "http://localhost:port/account/cart/id"}
```

Comment: are these request specs or controller specs?

Answer (score 1):

Try mocking it:

allow(@request).to receive(:referer).and_return('http://localhost:port/account/cart/id')